# At the same time, two identical elements can not be selected in dropDownList

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

Hello i am have two kendo ui drodDownList:

```
kendo-drop-down-list(
    ng-model = 'vm.firstList'
    k-data-source='vm.filterData'
    k-data-text-field='"title"'
    k-data-value-field='"name"'
    k-value-primitive='true'
    k-filter='"contains"'
    k-on-change='vm.onChange($event)'
)
```

and

```
kendo-drop-down-list(
    ng-model = 'vm.secondList'
    k-data-source='vm.filterData'
    k-data-text-field='"title"'
    k-data-value-field='"name"'
    k-value-primitive='true'
    k-filter='"contains"'
    k-on-change='vm.onChange($event)'
)
```

it is data source:

```
    this.filterData = [
        { name: 'Brown', title: 'Soier' },
        { name: 'Maks', title: 'Inkl' },
        { name: 'Lint', title: 'Baks' },
        { name: 'Hover', title: 'Niyou' }
    ]
```

they have same data source, and i am want when choosing item in first dd then remove this item from other dd (and likewise for the second). At the same time, two identical elements can not be selected.

Comment: in your onChange function, search for what you select and remove it from another filterData

Comment: i am want use same dataSource, in your solution i must use two dataSource for each dd ?

Comment: yes. You probably have to. In order for the ng-model in the first dropdown to keep the selection, the option has to be there. If you remove an option from another dropdown, the first dropdown will get re-compiled and ng-model will lose the selected option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution:

in first dd add:

```
k-on-change='vm.onFirstSelect(kendoEvent)'
k-data-source='vm.firstFilterElements'
```

for second dd:

```
k-on-change='vm.onSecondSelect(kendoEvent)'
k-data-source='vm.secondFilterElements'
```

in controller add:

```
        this.filterElements = [
            { name: 'Brown', title: 'Soier' },
            { name: 'Maks', title: 'Inkl' },
            { name: 'Lint', title: 'Baks' },
            { name: 'Hover', title: 'Niyou' }
         ]

    this.firstFilterElements = this.filterElements;
    this.secondFilterElements = this.filterElements;

onFirstSelect(e) {
    this.secondFilterElements = this.filterByItem(e);
}

onSecondSelect(e) {
    this.firstFilterElements = this.filterByItem(e);
}

filterByItem (e) {
    return this.filterElements.filter(function (el) {
        return el.name !== e.sender.dataItem(e.item)
           [e.sender.options.dataValueField];
    });
}
```

if someone can optimize it i will be glad)